# Are there negative energy states in QED?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

I was reading Weinberg I, when I came upon the following statement$^1$ (slightly edited by me):

> \begin{align}
> (\not p+m)u=ie\not A\\
> (\not p-m)v=ie\not A \tag{1}
> \end{align}
>
> The minus sign on the r.h.s. of the equation of $v$ shows that the $v$ are the famous "negative-energy" solutions of the Dirac equation. [...] Of course, for moderate external fields there are no negative-energy *states* in the theory.

What does Weinberg mean by this? For large enough $A$, is there some ket with $(H-E_0)|\varphi\rangle=-E_\varphi|\varphi\rangle$in the theory? (here, $E_0$ is the vacuum energy). Is this a flaw of the theory? Why *moderate* external field?

**My thoughts**

- I believe this has nothing to do with negative *norm* states of QED, because these are gauge-dependent while $E_\varphi$ is not.
- I believe this has nothing to do with bound states, as external fields have nothing to do with these, so the requirement for moderate external field wouldn't make sense.
- Lastly, I think it *might* be related to $H$ being unbounded below. The QED interaction is $A\bar \psi\psi$, which is cubic in the fields. Therefore, "$H\to-\infty$ as $A\to-\infty$". But $H_\mathrm{QED}$ being unbounded would be something awful: the theory wouldn't have a ground state, so I don't think this is the answer either.

---

$^1$: The Quantum Theory of Fields, Volume 1: Foundations, page 567.

Comment: Bound states don't really have negative energy per se, they have less positive energy.

Comment: My pleasure. I can't answer your question I'm afraid. you could always [ask Weinberg](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~weintech/weinberg.html).

Comment: @JohnDuffield: I don't know what that is supposed to mean. How do I distinguish "less positive energy" from "it looks exactly like the same energy as in the "normal" particle"?

Comment: @CuriousOne I believe he means that, say you have an electron and a positron. Then the energy of the system is less than $.511\ \mathrm{MeV}+.511\ \mathrm{MeV}$, but still greater than zero...

Comment: @CuriousOne : a hydrogen atom is a bound state. The mass is 13.6eV/c² less than the mass of the free proton and electron.  If you consider the proton as fixed to simplify the situation, when you pull the electron away you add energy to it and increase its mass. We know of no negative-energy particles or objects.

Comment: @JohnDuffield: I understand that, but what are free particles bound to? There is no background/lattice etc.. The particle/hole model is a very unfitting choice for what is a perfectly Lorentz invariant vacuum and it only works because the total energy of the background is very large compared to the energy difference caused by the bound state. The true problem here is that both particle and anti-particle have positive mass, but that mass-energy is behind the charge conservation wall. The hydrogen groundstate energy, by the way, is behind the angular momentum wall... can't get it without photon.

Comment: @CuriousOne : I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. But can I volunteer this: space isn't nothing, the E=hf photon is a wave in space, we can diffract electrons, the electron and the positron have the opposite chirality, and IMHO each is a wave bound to itself. In [atomic orbitals electrons exist as standing waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Electron_properties). Pull the electron away from the proton, and it still exists as a standing wave. Standing wave, standing field.

Comment: @JohnDuffield: What I mean is that massive particle-antiparticle pairs are not a self-consistent description of the vacuum. They don't have an energy unless the photons they annihilate into are part of the description. You can't have electrons/positrons without photons. To call out an annihilation energy without talking about the field that it goes into is simply not self-consistent physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does involve bound states. For an electron in the Coulomb field $A(r)=-\frac{Ze}{r}$ that arises from a nucleus (of mass $m$), the lowest energy is $E_0=m\sqrt{1-(2Z\alpha)^2}$ where $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant. This is positive for $Z\le\frac{1}{2\alpha}$, which is what Weinberg means by "moderate" fields.

The assumption so far was that the nuclues is pointlike. When $Z$ is equal to or greater than this critical value $\frac{1}{2\alpha}$, we must instead view the nucleus as a finite-sized object. When this is done, you'll see that the energy levels become negative, up until the "continuum limit" value of $-m$.

Comment: Some relevant references come from the physicist V.R. Khalilov.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense! So W. is talking about bound states *with the external field* and not QED bound states per se (e.g., a positronium), right? You say that  the minimum energy is $-m$, which means that the Hamiltonian **is** bounded below, right?